# Переопределение значения полей при наследовании C#

Tags: c#, классы, наследование

Здравствуйте!
Есть следующий код:

```
class FirstClass
{
    private string Prefix = "F.";
    internal string Name;

    public FirstClass(string Name)
    {
        this.Name = Prefix + Name;
    }
}

class SecondClass : FirstClass
{
    string Prefix = "S.";
    public SecondClass(string Name) : base(Name) { }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var Var1 = new SecondClass("SecondClass");
        Console.WriteLine(Var1.Name);
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне в классе `SecondClass` переназначить переменную         `Prefix`, не используя конструктор класса `SecondClass`. Модификатор `new` не работает.
Спасибо!

Comment: наследованием можно переопределить _поведение_, это функции, поля функциями не являются.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Замените поля свойствами и сделайте их в базовом классе виртуальными. А в наследниках переопределяйте на свой вкус. И, разумеется, измените модификаторы доступа как минимум на protected

Comment: Да, только `private` нельзя переопределять. Поэтому у поля надо изменить спецификатор на `protected`.

Comment: @Mirdin да, разумеется. Я не обратил внимание на то, что поля private, подумав по умолчанию, что раз человек хочет использовать поля в наследнике, то они у него как минимум protected

Comment: @DreamChild то что нужно! Большое спасибо, удачи Вам.

Answer (score 4):

Если ваш компилятор поддерживает C# 6.0, то вы можете написать следующим образом

```
using System;

namespace virtual_properties
{
    class FirstClass
    {
        protected virtual string Prefix { get; } = "F.";
        protected string Name;

        public FirstClass(string Name)
        {
            this.Name = Prefix + Name;
            Console.WriteLine(this.Name);
        }
    }

    class SecondClass : FirstClass
    {
        protected override string Prefix { get; } = "S.";
        public SecondClass(string Name) : base(Name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this.Name);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FirstClass c1  = new FirstClass("First");
            SecondClass c2 = new SecondClass("Second");

        }
    }
}
```

Вывод на консоль

```
F.First
S.Second
S.Second
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ! Возьму на заметку.

Comment: @K.Oleg Я сам первый раз в жизни написал такой код.:) Главное - чтобы компилятор поддерживал C# 6.0. Вы можете скачать бесплатно MS VS Community 2015, который это позволяет делать.

Comment: @K.Oleg вы можете получить предупреждение "Virtual member call in constructor". Посмотрите [описание здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182331.aspx), чтобы понять в чем его смысл.